# C# Lambda Query. Convert Cell value to DateTime to get year

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a Excel file im reading in with ACE.OLEDB.

Some of the columns have DateTime values (DD MMM YYYY) but they all come back as String, this is fine.

however when I'm trying to utilise the DataTable in my lambda I am getting errors.

I've tried using

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

var getOldDates = dt
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Where(d => DateTime.Parse(
     d.Field<string>("Date of Birth"), cultureInfo).Date.Year == 1900);
```

**"String reference not set to an instance of a String.\r\nParameter name: s"**

```
var getOldDates2 = dt
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Where(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.Field<string>("Date of Birth")).Date.Year == 1900);
```

**"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."**

Im guessing its something probably simple.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please preview your post when writing it - the code is really hard to read when it's not formatted appropriately. But my guess is that `d.Field("Date of Birth")` is returning null for some row...

Comment: Hi, not sure what happened to the post, when i previewed it, everything looked fine. yes. that seems to be the issue

d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Field<string>("Date of Birth")) &&
                    Convert.ToDateTime(d.Field<string>("Date of Birth")).Date.Year == 1900);

has fixed it, thanks